# How to create a trigger in SQL Server that fires only right before the transaction will be committed

Tags: sql-server, triggers, transactions, foreign-keys, rollback

So I ran into an issue that goes as follows:

 - I have table A.

 - I have table B which has a foreign key to table A.

 - I have a trigger on table A that ensures that every item in table A has at least one row in table B pointing to it (through the foreign key).

 - The trigger runs for "insert" commands.


Now the issue is that when I insert into table A, the trigger raises the error because table B doesn't have a row with the foreign key to the new row in table A yet. The row on Table B will be inserted by the end of the transaction but the trigger does not give me the chance.


So what is a good solution to the problem? Is there a way to tell a trigger to run only after the last command in the transaction is executed?

Comment: why are you using triggers to enforce the foreign key relationship? That's already done **BY** the foreign key for you. What you want is a trigger on A to do the required insert into B

Comment: Move your trigger from table A to table B

Comment: Marc B - The trigger is not to enforce the foreign key. The trigger is to enforce that table B has at least on row referencing table A.

Comment: LastCoder - I already have a version on table B, but I need another in table A because one might insert into table A without inserting a corresponding row on table B.

Comment: *"Is there a way to tell a trigger to run only after the last command in the transaction is executed?"* -> No. And I wonder how will this discussion develop.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a trigger to fire on table A, but do not know if there are any corresponding rows in table b, you should use an "INSTEAD OF" trigger.  This will allow you to check table B before inserting rows into Table A.  If there is a match in table B, proceed with the insert into A, otherwise, add the row to b and then A, or skip the data that doesnt match and return an error to the application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: The problem is that I cannot insert into table B before inserting into table A. Remember that one of the columns in table B is a foreign key to table A, and it cannot be set until the row in table A is inserted and assigned an id, id that will then be used for the foreign key column in table B.

Comment: You wont be able to do what you want outside the scope of the instead of trigger.  You can use the instead of trigger on table A to do the insert into a then use the output clause to load table B.